# Fetch data from API in DataTable with CORS Origin error

Tags: express, datatable, cors, http-status-code-404

I have an API that accepts has localhost:3000 added in its Allowed CORS origin list.

I donot have the access to the server but client mentioned "localhost:3000" is added.

Now im trying to make a request to that API using express/node and load it in Jquery DataTable with proxy server running on localhost:3000 but still receiving CORS error on browser.

HTML/Jquery code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>API Demo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <table id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Visits</th>
                <th>Pageviews</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'api/stats/upwork_demo/?key=secret&date_from=2023-3-1&date_to=2023-4-1',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    // Initialize DataTables
                    $('#table').DataTable({
                        data: data.data,
                        columns: [
                            { title: 'Date', data: 'date' },
                            { title: 'Visits', data: 'visits' },
                            { title: 'Pageviews', data: 'pageviews' }
                        ]
                    });
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Express code:

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();

// Proxy middleware
const apiProxy = createProxyMiddleware('/', {
  target: 'https://stats.hostname.com',
  changeOrigin: true,
});

app.use(apiProxy);

// Serve static files
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Start server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Proxy server listening on port 3000');
});
```

I really new to this. This is what my browser network->headers tab says

Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:3000/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Sometimes it throws CORS error too.

Basically all I want is to load data. I was successfully able to do it in simple javascript/jquery with another test API but when client gave me this it had this CORS restriction and to my understanding, I have to do it through a proxy server now which is causing me all sorts of issues.

BTW stats.hostname.com is a dummy API. I will replace it with the original one later.

Any help would really be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow is Frontend(client side) => proxy server => target API server.

A working example:

`server-a.js`(*proxy server*):

```js
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();
const apiProxy = createProxyMiddleware('/api', {
  target: 'http://localhost:3001',
  changeOrigin: true,
  logLevel: 'debug'
});
app.use(apiProxy);
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Proxy server listening on port 3000');
});
```

`server-b.js`(*target API server*):

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/api/stats/upwork_demo', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ data: [1, 2, 3] })
})

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('API server listening on port 3001');
});
```

`public/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/api/stats/upwork_demo/?key=secret&date_from=2023-3-1&date_to=2023-4-1',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          console.log('data: ', data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log('Error: ' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The logs of `server-a.js` after the client send an HTTP request to it.

```bash
✗ node server-a.js
[HPM] Proxy created: /api  -> http://localhost:3001
[HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events: [ 'error', 'close' ]
Proxy server listening on port 3000
[HPM] GET /api/stats/upwork_demo/?key=secret&date_from=2023-3-1&date_to=2023-4-1 -> http://localhost:3001
```

The console logs of the browser:

[image]

Comment: So to my understanding there will be 3 files, server-a.js, server-b.js and index.html right? And what command do I have to run in terimal? node server-a.js?

Comment: @FahadHussain Start the API server in a shell session, then start the proxy server in another. The proxy server serves the static file like `index.html`